# How to call didInsertElement when a template is rendered since View is deprecated in Ember 1.13

Tags: ember.js

I'm updating to Ember 1.13 and I want to fade in a background on the application template I use to call didInsertElement from the View.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        $('#login-bg').fadeIn(600);
    }
});
```

This throws a deprecated because Views are going away. Does Ember create a component for the template? This does not work:

```
App.ApplicationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        $('#login-bg').fadeIn(600);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no default application component working behind the scenes as of yet, but you could make one and wrap your application template in it like this:

```
// app/templates/application.hbs
{{#application-area}}
  {{outlet}}
{{/application-area}}


// app/templates/components/application-area.hbs
<div id="login-bg">
  {{yield}}
</div>


// app/components/application-area.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement () {
    Ember.$('#login-bg').fadeIn(600);
  }
});
```

Comment: Also if you're doing animated transitions like this, I would highly recommend the [Liquid Fire Addon](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire) for Ember.

Comment: Yeah that works. But what is the point of templates if you always have to put things in components to have access to lifecycle functions like didInsertView and willDestroyElement?

Comment: They are planning on making routable components which would back your template, but until that is done you can still use the view, it is just being deprecated to warn you from creating gobs of views and to move over to components where possible.